# Resolving undershoot and overshoot geometries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a polyline layer and I used topology checker to identify the undershoot and the overshoot geometries. Now I want to resolve the undershoot and overshoot geometries in the polyline layer in QGIS.

Grass v.clean is not giving me the expected results. Is there anyway to do that in qgis?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [QAD Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/), it has the functions of trim overshoot polyline features and extend undershoot polyline features.

[image]

However, you should do editing manually. You cannot do it automatically as you can get using v.clean function of GRASS.

Another way is using v.clean and use the `break` cleaning tool. After running the tool, calculate the length of the lines. Then, use `Select by attribute` to select the length of these small overhooting lines and delete them. At least you can get rid of those overshooting lines but with caution to not delete other small lines that you still need them.

Comment: if the no of features is less we can do manually but if the number of features(under/overshoot) are more doing manually is a tedious job.So thats trying to find the available options to do in qgis.